# How to extract the 'LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG' element value into <td>

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery

In the below example cases we have hard coded for 'LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG' element in xslt and trying to automated using xslt 1.0:

**Case 1:** If there is no text before '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;' (i.e. after '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;' in this case could be <bold>, <italic> .. etc. elements and we need retain those also).
<LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Kaikoura South Breakwater Head</LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>
**Should be**
Kaikoura South Breakwater Head

**Case 2:** If text have before '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;'
<LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>Kaikōura South Breakwater Head&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Kaikoura South Breakwater Head</LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>
**Should be**
Kaikōura South Breakwater Head

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NM_LIGHT_LIST_RECORD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PRODUCT_REF>
    <PRODUCTVER_ID>572902</PRODUCTVER_ID>
    <UPDATE_KEY>4277</UPDATE_KEY>
    <CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_LIST>
        <CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_VERSION_ID>57509415</CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_VERSION_ID>
        <CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_VERSION_ID>57508780</CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_VERSION_ID>
    </CONTRIBUTING_FEATURE_LIST>
</PRODUCT_REF>
<NATIONAL_NUMBER xsi:nil="true"/>
<INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER>4277</INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER>
<!--<LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Kaikoura South Breakwater Head</LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>-->
<LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>Kaikōura South Breakwater Head&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Kaikoura South Breakwater Head</LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG>
<POSITION>
    <LATITUDE>42 25.56</LATITUDE>
    <LONGITUDE>173 40.85</LONGITUDE>
</POSITION>
<LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS_ENG>Iso  G 2s</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS_ENG>
<LUM_GEO_RANGE>6</LUM_GEO_RANGE>
<LIGHT_HEIGHT>6</LIGHT_HEIGHT>
<DESC_STRUCT_HEIGHT_ENG> Black and white Horizontal stripes,  metal pole<p style="text-align:center;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">3</p></DESC_STRUCT_HEIGHT_ENG>
<OBSERVATION_ENG>
    <br/>
</OBSERVATION_ENG>
<NM_LIGHTS_OBMNZ>No</NM_LIGHTS_OBMNZ>
</NM_LIGHT_LIST_RECORD>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<table xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" style="width:100%;font-size:8pt;">
    <tr style="vertical-align:text-top;">
        <td style="width:10%;font-weight:bold;">4277</td>
        <td style="width:20%;">Kaikōura South Breakwater Head</td>
        <td style="width:14%;text-align:right;">42 25.56<br>173 40.85</td>
        <td style="width:14%;padding-left:15px;">Iso  G 2s</td>
        <td style="width:5%;">6</td>
        <td style="width:5%;">6</td>
        <td style="width:20%;"> Black and white Horizontal stripes,  metal pole
            <p xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" style="text-align:center;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;">3</p>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20%;">
            <OBSERVATION_ENG xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <br>
            </OBSERVATION_ENG>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

<xsl:template match="/NM_LIGHT_LIST_RECORD">
    <table style="width:100%;font-size:8pt;">
        <tr style="vertical-align:text-top;">
            <td style="width:10%;font-weight:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER"/></td>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <!--<xsl:copy-of select="LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG/node()"/>-->
                <xsl:variable name="NOBJNM">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG/node()"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$NOBJNM = 'Kaikōura South Breakwater Head&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Kaikoura South Breakwater Head'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Kaikōura South Breakwater'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$NOBJNM = 'Māpua Port Pile&lt;NOBJNM&gt;Mapua Port Pile'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Māpua Port Pile'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$NOBJNM"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </td>
            <td style="width:14%;text-align:right;">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(POSITION/LATITUDE,'NEWS','')"/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(POSITION/LONGITUDE,'NEWS','')"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width:14%;padding-left:15px;"><xsl:value-of select="LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS_ENG"/></td>
            <td style="width:5%;"><xsl:value-of select="LIGHT_HEIGHT"/></td>
            <td style="width:5%;"><xsl:copy-of select="LUM_GEO_RANGE/node()"/></td>
            <td style="width:20%;"><xsl:copy-of select="DESC_STRUCT_HEIGHT_ENG/node()"/>
                <xsl:variable name="height" select="STRUCT_HEIGHT"/>
                <xsl:if test="$height != ''"><p style="text-align:center;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 2px;"><xsl:value-of select="$height"/></p></xsl:if>
            </td>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <xsl:copy-of select="OBSERVATION_ENG"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS='Temporary'">
                        <br/><strong> T </strong>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS='Racon temporarily discontinued'">
                        <br/><strong> TR </strong>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS='Preliminary'">
                        <br/><strong> P </strong>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS='Temporarily discontinued (non-light AtoN)'">
                        <br/><strong> TD </strong>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS='Temporarily extinguished (light AtoN)'">
                        <br/><strong> TE </strong>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise/>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="NM_LIGHTS_STATUS != ''">
                    <strong><xsl:value-of select="../../../NM_YEAR_PUB"/></strong>  
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL #** http://xsltransform.net/94hvTAf/663

Answer (score 0):

Albeit this could be done with a single XPath expression, I will follow your XSLT style:

```
<xsl:variable 
    name="NOBJNM" 
    select="substring-before(LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG, '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;')"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$NOBJNM">
        <xsl:value-of select="$NOBJNM"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of 
            select="substring-after(LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG, '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;')"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: @Alejando - If we're using 
        <xsl:value-of 
            select="substring-after(LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG, '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;')"/> in this case elements will be miss like <bold> , <italic> ...etc.

Comment: That's not clear from your samples. Might there be elements before a text node with `'&lt;NOBJNM&gt;'` string or ony after? Provide complete examples, please.

Comment: @Alejando - we can try in existing example to add <bold>xyz<bold> element after '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;. and avoid before '&lt;NOBJNM&gt;.

Comment: I have not trouble in revisting the answer, but the use of `&lt;NOBJNM&gt;` make me thinks there is some encoding of parsed data into unparsed data. That pose some alerts. That's also why your sample should reflect that "the mark" is a text node child of  `LOC_NAME_CHART_NUM_ENG` element and not a descendant (ie. inside some other element, creating the necesity for a breaking criterion)